# Reordering panels of variables in multiple scatterplot based on correlation coefficient / lm line (using ggplot in r)

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatterplot with several panels for each variable. I would like to reorder the panels based on their lm line or correlation coefficients (e.g. from negative to positive).

So in this example below, I would like the first row to inlude the plots of `am`, `drat`, `vs`and the last plot the be `wt`

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

corr_eqn = function(x, y, digits = 2) {
  corr_coef = round(cor(x, y), digits = digits)
  paste("italix(r) == ", corr_coef)
}

mtcars_gath <- mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") 

labels = data.frame(x = 300, y = 10, label = corr_eqn(mtcars_gath$value, mtcars_gath$mpg))

mtcars_plot = mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", fullrange = TRUE)+
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), parse = TRUE)
mtcars_plot
```

Furthermore, I was not able to include correlation coefficients for each of the plots (as seen in this example).

Any hint is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Your example is not reproducible as we don't have `political_var_values`. Can you make it all about mtcars?

Comment: @prosoitos sorry, I didn't see that - thanks for pointing it out. I edited it respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Chris answer, if you want to add also the labels you need to use the same trick with `factor`:

```
mtcast_gat <- mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value")

#Corr function:
    corr_eqn = function(x, y, digits = 2) {
      corr_coef = round(cor(x, y), digits = digits)
      paste("italic(r) == ", corr_coef)
    }

labels <- mtcast_gat %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% # group by variable
  summarise(label = corr_eqn(value, mpg), # get the formatted corr
            cor = round(cor(value, mpg), 2)) %>% # get the numeric corr
  mutate(x = 300, y = -2000) # we add labels x,y


level <- arrange(labels,desc(cor))$var # level arrangement

labels <- labels %>% 
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels=levs)) # arrangement for labels
```

Then we can plot:

```
mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels=levs)) %>% # correct arrangement
  arrange(var) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), parse = TRUE) + # add labels
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris and Rlave, this is brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the order of the panels, you need to change the factor levels for your faceting variable,  `var`.

First get your unique `var` values in the order you want them plotted:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars_gath <- mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") 

# calculate the correlation coefficients between each var and mpg
cor_df <- data.frame(var = unique(mtcars_gath$var),
                cor = sapply(unique(mtcars_gath$var), function(x) cor.test(mtcars[,x],mtcars$mpg)$estimate)
                ) 
# get your vector of var in the order you want for plotting
levs <- arrange(cor_df,desc(cor))$var
```

Update your `var` column to a factor with the levels in the correct order and these will be used as the order for plotting panels.

```
mtcars_plot <- mtcars_gath %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels=levs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", fullrange = F)

mtcars_plot
```

[image]